# python split into n array(batch) and try to group same id in one batch math

Tags: python, json

I have a json object:

```
json ={'message_id': '1', 'token': 'a'}
{'message_id': '2', 'token': 'b'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'c'}
{'message_id': '4', 'token': 'd'}
{'message_id': '4', 'token': 'e'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'f'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'g'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'h'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'm'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'k'}
```

I want to batch the token into trunks to pass to API call, the catch is try to fit tokens with same message_id in one batch if possible, the idea is try not to split same messageid's token into 2 batches.

for example, I want to divide the 10 messages into 2 batch, that means 5 tokens in each array. 
So in the example above, 1 has 4 tokens, 2 has 1 token, 3 has 3 tokens, 4 has 2 tokens which adds up to 10.
The ideal way to group this is 4+1 and 2+3.
the final result I am looking for is:

```
[['a', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'b'] ,['c','d','e','m','k']]
```

because 'a', 'f', 'g', 'h' has same message id so have them in one batch instead of split messge_id 1's token into 2 arrays

I think this is more mathmatical than coding. Cuz I am able to batch them easily with the following code if I dont have to consider the grouping under same id in one batch

```
def batch(list, n):
    for i in range(0, len(list), n):
        print(i)
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

I will elaborate further, the goal is to split **m** messages into **n** batches(input variable), and try to group same message_id into same batch if possible, I understand there's always overfloat possibility and if one message_id has more than m/n tokens, which exceeds the limit and it has to go 2 batches.

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood your question well. Do you want to maximize the number of equal `message_id`s in groups?

Comment: no no just try not to split 2 messages with same id into different batches, the idea is try to fit same messageid in one batch if possible

Comment: And if it isn't possible? What's the criteria then?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you tried solving this on paper, writing some pseudocode?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, if not possible then it has to be split up. I edited my question for clarity. Thank you Andrej!

Comment: @AMC, I edited my questions for more clarity let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources:

1.[operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

2.[Using zip_longest to chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52022535/1913726)

```
import itertools as it
import json
import operator as op

# Copied and pasted from the question
messages_json = """{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'a'}
{'message_id': '2', 'token': 'b'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'c'}
{'message_id': '4', 'token': 'd'}
{'message_id': '4', 'token': 'e'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'f'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'g'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'h'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'm'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'k'}""".replace(
    "'", '"' # replace single quote with double quote for JSON
).splitlines()  # List of JSON strings

messages = (json.loads(item) for item in messages_json)

key = op.itemgetter("message_id") # Use to sort by message_id.
LIMIT = 5

values = (item['token'] for item in sorted(messages, key=key))
for chunk in it.zip_longest(*it.repeat(iter(values), LIMIT), fillvalue=False):
    print([item for item in chunk if item])
```

OUTPUT is a list with a max length of LIMIT with the values of the messages tokens sorted by message_ids:

```
['a', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'b']
['c', 'm', 'k', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: sorry this is not the end result I want to see.

Comment: Please write out the result you want to see.

Comment: [['a', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'b'] ,['c','d','e','m','k']] @dmmfll

Comment: The order of the second list differs from yours because the messages are first sorted in this code by message_id. Does the order matter? Or just the chunk size?

Comment: could you please explain to me the math method behind it? I dont quite understand the zip_longest method

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29009933/1913726 There are a lot of Python concepts packed into that line of code. Familiarize yourself with the built-in `iter` and how transposition works with zip_longest(*iterable). Imagine a diagonal slicing mechanism down a list of rows. In the mean time, I will see if I can find a post about it. I practiced with it for weeks before I felt like it was familiar.

Comment: If the code is the solution you were seeking, please accept and up-vote. Thank you.

Comment: this failed the test cases with message_id 4 split to 2 batch: """{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'a'}
{'message_id': '2', 'token': 'b'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'c'}
{'message_id': '4', 'token': 'd'}
{'message_id': '4', 'token': 'e'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'f'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'g'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'h'}
{'message_id': '3', 'token': 'm'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'k'}
{'message_id': '1', 'token': 'z'}"""